# About silent Print of PDF in chrome using iframe

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, itext, adobe

My code project is asp web form, and I use iTextSharp to embed javascript to 
pdf, like following:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER);
doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, outstream);
doc.Open();
....
string jsText = "var res = app.setTimeOut('var pp = this.getPrintParams();pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.silent;this.print(pp);this.close();', 200);";
PdfAction js = PdfAction.JavaScript(jsText, writer);
writer.AddJavaScript(js);
doc.Close();
```

Then it can make the browser auto-print pdf each time. It work on IE, but in chrome, it fail, is there anyone know the exact reason and how to fix that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I fount it is impossible to directly print PDF using silent print. I think it is the secure issue, and the only way is to set the default setting of 
chrome, see: https://support.dealpos.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001463387-Printing-Without-a-Print-Preview-in-Chrome-Browser